# Bottom paragraph doesn't display correct in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I have tried several ways to be able to display the bottom paragraph as normal as in other browsers, but it does not display properly in IE8.

Here is a link to the problem: http://get-connected.com/content.asp?id=4111

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)...

Answer (score 0):

add parameter display: inline-table; to the paragraph div css

or

remove margin and padding from paragraph div for the second paragraph
add padding and margin to column2 div.

Comment: thanks, could you answer me why I would have to take out the height? Thought if I put a hight to my .paragraph class it would then be fine. But I'm open to any information as I think its a good learning curve for me thanks :)

Comment: you height scales automatically based on amount of content in the div. if you get height to be bigger than it should be, you get unexpected behaviors.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you have a `height: 140px;` on your `.paragraph`. You need to remove that.

Comment: thanks, could you answer me why I would have to take out the height? Thought if I put a hight to my .paragraph class it would then be fine. But I'm open to any information as I think its a good learning curve for me thanks :)

Comment: Adding a height constrains the content to that specific height, so in the case of a paragraph, the text ran outside of the height of the box containing it, leaving the overlap you saw. You could either leave out the height (letting the browser figure out the height automatically), or change `height:140px` to `min-height:140px` if you want the paragraphs to always be AT LEAST 140pxs, but allowing expansion if necessary.